# mp4 (h.264 + mp3) to icecast to html5 video tag on mobile

Tags: html, video, mp4, vlc, icecast

I want to show on my page transcoded rtsp stream from live camera. I use vlc to transcode and send stream to Icecast.
I've been using ogg+theora and I could see my video in desktop browsers: Firefox, Chrome. But coudn't see on mobile - as I understand, it's not supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=ogg

It looks like I could use mp4 to show my video on almost every device:
http://caniuse.com/#search=mp4

But I can't setup Icecast for receiving stream. I changed mount point from 'example.ogg' to 'example.mp4', but it's not working. Does Icecast supports mp4? If yes, how to setup?

Answer (score 0):

Icecast does not officially support h264/mp3, as those are nonfree codecs. Icecast will just broadcast them without any modifications, depending on the container this might work or not.